# How to set values as "NULL" in thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf as a UI framework. I am pulling data from a database and storing it as an object. When I display my values in a table I have some cells that are blank. Instead of it being blank, how can I enter the values as "NULL"?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>years in school</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="student : ${studentinfo}">
        <td th:text="${student.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${student.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${student.age}"></td>
        <td th:text="${student.years}">NULL</td>
        <!-- attempted -->
        <td th:text="${student.years != null} ? ${student.years}">NULL</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some students have `null` in years. But when I am displaying it in my UI, it is just a blank cell. I want to display "NULL" if the cell is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to use the rest of the ternary expression :P

```
<td th:text = "${student.years != null ? student.years : 'NULL'}" />
```

Comment: And what if I want to pass null as null, not as a string 'NULL" ?